# Using requested XHR data while actually loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

maybe i just got it wrong but... im requesting "large" files via ajax (180mb - 500mb). i thought that im able to fetch and use the data with the method `URL.createObjectURL` while its actually loading? i need the requested data within 5 seconds but its acutually loading 16 seconds.

1. ajax request
2. `xhr.onload` (worked within 5 seconds or faster, locally, but not live)
3. within the onload (or progress, onreadystatechange (i tried)) i used `URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response)` to get the data

```
var nxtclp = new XMLHttpRequest();

nxtclp.onload = function() {
 get_src = URL.createObjectURL(nxtclp.response);
 that.preloadSource = get_src;
};

nxtclp.open("GET", "media/vid.mp4");
nxtclp.responseType = "blob";
nxtclp.send();
```

is there any way to playback data while loading ?

Comment: What is reason for using ajax for media file in first place?

Comment: well its for an interactive movie... so at "90%" of the actual clip there comes a decision for the user where he can choose how the movie continues... if he interacts with the decision elements i know what the file for the next clip is and to provide a fluid transition from one clip to the other im not loading files at the end of the clip, i load dem with ajax on interaction with decision elements so i have 6 seconds to preload the next file -  thats what i tried.

Comment: Still doesn't explain why ajax is needed

Comment: damn, never saw that answer - what other solutions then ajax would you know ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `autoplay` attribute at `<video>` element

> [`autoplay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-autoplay)
>
> A Boolean attribute; if specified, the video automatically begins to
>   play back as soon as it can do so without stopping to finish loading
>   the data.

```html
<video controls autoplay src="http://mirrors.creativecommons.org/movingimages/webm/ScienceCommonsJesseDylan_240p.webm">
</video>
```

alternatively, using `javascript`

```js
var video = document.createElement("video");
video.autoplay = true;
video.controls = true;
video.onloadedmetadata = (e) => {
  console.log(video.readyState);
  document.body.appendChild(e.path[0])
}
video.src = "http://mirrors.creativecommons.org/movingimages/webm/ScienceCommonsJesseDylan_240p.webm";
```

```html
<body>
</body>
```